# c#,excel: getting range info

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

i have a c# code which gets the (excel-2007) worksheets used range as follows

```
 Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.GetActiveWorksheet();
 Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)ws.UsedRange;
```

for the current worksheet i know exactly that range is A1:HM232,...but in the future that range may change... how is it possible to get the range info such as A1:HM232 from the used range info?

i can get the rows.count and columns.count... but how to get info such as "HM"?

the reason behind this is that i'm trying to put it later on a formula like

```
=Sheet1!A1:HM232...
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I this this method should do it:

```
range.get_AddressLocal(range.Rows.Count ,range.Columns.Count ,XlReferenceStyle.xlA1 ,null ,ws.UsedRange);
```